# Wireless Networked Sensor Light?

Tags: lighting, motion-sensor

I would like to install a group of outdoor sensor lights that will turn on all sensor lights when one of them is triggered, like [NetBright](http://www.mrbeams.com/products/netbright-wireless-security-lights), but I do not want battery-operated ones.  Are there products out there that can do this?

Comment: Assuming your replacing existing lights and there isn't an extra wire, you would want to look at networked solutions--either RF or line carrier technology.  If this is a new install and new wiring, [run an extra conductor and hardwire them.](http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/80490/multiple-motion-detectors-wired-together)

Comment: replacing existing lights and there isn't an extra wire.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there are. Some speak the X10 carrier-current signalling protocol, some use more modern  communications. Obviously you would need to buy compatible components.

A good home-automation catalog or a website on that topic could give you product suggestions; we don't generally do that here.