# How should dual motion sensors be connected?

Tags: motion-sensor

One supply parallel to connecting two motion sensors. In between lights connected. Lights common for two sensor.

In same time two sensors activated in the sense any problem happens sensor and lights.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange. I think you'll find your  question asked and answered here.  https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/80490/multiple-motion-detectors-wired-together  If I'm wrong, please add more detail to your question.

Comment: I didn't understand that. My doubt in load same . If same time two sensors activated , two sensor output connected in same load .it will affect the sensors

Comment: Not if the sensors are any good.

Answer (score 1):

I have done this with up to 3 sensors (all on the same circuit) quite a few times with generic motion sensors for myself and customers that liked the way it worked, I tie the reds together but these all must be on the same branch circuit. Just a note you may want an override like if having a party to light up the house / driveway constantly I did this by using a 3 way switch one side went to the lights directly the other to the motion sensors, with the switch in the up position they were on 100%, with the switch in the down position it powered the motion sensors and when any or all the sensors were triggered the lights will stay on until the last sensor times out. The only problem with this setup is when 1 sensor fails on it takes a bit of work to troubleshoot but on my own home I think I have lost 2 sensors since 2000 on a 3 sensor system.