# How can a circuit be designed with a switched live connected to multiple PIR motion sensors? [UK]

Tags: electrical, lighting, uk

If you want a light or generic circuit to be switched by multiple PIR sensors, how is this best achieved? For instance you might have 4 sensors on the corners of your house and if any of them detect something, the circuit goes live.

I've seen how to do it for 2 sensors but can't figure out how to extrapolate for a variable number, other than adding an extra live in parallel for each switch(!).

I have seen a question talking about this for the US and while electricity is the same there, the way things are done is subtly different so I would like a UK-specific answer.

Is there a way that lets you add multiple PIRs flexibly once cables are already installed?

Comment: Are low voltage (24V or so) "powerpack" type PIR sensors a thing in the UK, or are you limited to wallbox-type, line-voltage PIR sensors?

Comment: just make each node wireless (i like wifi) and you can implement any combination of sensors and behavior you can dream of from a central controller. I have several PIRs that can trigger the same lights, as well as indication LEDs. So, I can see movement anywhere in the house, and sensors at either end of a long hall will illuminate it (if the time of day and existing light level demand it).

Comment: @dandavis I was actually wondering about that but searching didn't turn up products that seemed good - it was all smart-home stuff and I don't want it routing through Google/Amazon. Are you aware of any particular brands or search terms because I agree if it was on WiFi/Zwave with a central hub this could be pretty neat.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel the ones I've seen are all mains switches but that might not mean much

Answer (score 3):

I answered your core question [here](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/91897/47125). Just go into photoshop and copy-paste as many more sensors and lights as you please.  Go read it, but let me re-color that for UK.

[image]

The only trick is going to be UK wire and cable.  You need 3 wires:

- Always-hot to supply sensors
- Switched-hot for sensors to send power to lamps
- Neutral for everybody.

So you need 3-core + earth cable.  But while North American /3+gnd cable accommodates neutral, I note that common UK 3-core+earth cable does not.  You need a light-blue neutral.  Your 3-core appears to be black brown gray.  I don't know if you're *allowed* to get light-blue tape and re-mark the gray wire to be neutral, or whether you need to source special 3-core that has a blue wire.

Comment: Yeah colours on multicore is confusing here, it's due to some standard I forget. You can indeed use whatever as long as it's clearly labeled, at least I've seen professionals do it this way. Many thanks for the UK-specific version :)

Comment: Oh - could you categorically state which is switched Vs permanent live (hot) between brown and red to make this totally canonical?

Comment: @Mr.Boy Yeah, I was going crazy trying to figure out which color for switched-hot.   I forgot red is the OLD hot color.  In my drawing brown=always-hot red=switched-hot.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, this is done by
relays (may also be called contactors. I forget if there's also a UK specific term for them.)

Whether low-voltage (which have some advantages, apparently including lower cost sensors) or line voltage, each sensor operates one relay. If the sensors are low voltage, the relay coil is low-voltage - if the sensors are line voltage, the relay coil is line-voltage. The relay contacts are line voltage, and connect between a hot (live) supply and a switched hot (live) connected to all the lights you want to switch. If more than one sensor is active, more than one relay may be energized, but they all connect to the same hot (live) circuit and the same switched hot (live) line, so there's no problem with that.

An alternate approach for low voltage sensors is to have the sensors all switch relays that are using low voltage on the coils **and** contacts, which connect to one **low-voltage coil, line voltage contacts** relay that switches the light circuit. This may be to have more of the wiring run be low voltage (where that eases methods of wiring) or because the line-voltage contact relay may cost more, so you can buy just one of those.

One reason to prefer relays to tying the outputs of multiple sensors together is that relays are not bothered by voltage on the output when they are off - some "electronic-switching" sensor outputs may not tolerate that, if they were designed to be the only switch on the output device. Others may tolerate being tied together, but by using a relay, you can be sure, without needing to know details that the sensor maker may not share.